# Proving this property of a tournament graph by induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, induction, proof-verification

I am working on practicing proofs by induction. Can you please take a look at the proof below and tell me if I proved it correctly? I am particularly worried about the inductive step.

> Definition 1. A tournament graph is a directed graph G = (V, E) without loops, in which for
>   every two vertices u and v, exactly one of (u, v) or (v, u) are in E.
>
> Prove using induction that for every tournament graph G = (V, E), it holds that 
>   E = [|V|(|V|-1)]/2.
>
> Let the statement be P(n). For the base of a graph with 1 vertex, it holds that P(1) which is:
>   E = 0 = 1(1-1)/2 = 2. We can now assume that for some arbitrary positive integer K that: 
>   E = k(k-1)/2. To complete the inductive step, we must use the inductive hypothesis to prove k+1 holds for: E = (k+1)((k+1)-1) / 2 = (k+1)k/2 By the inductive hypothesis, we know that this equals:
>   k(k-1)/2 + k = k(k-1) +2k/2 = k^2 - k + 2k/2 = k(k - 1 + 2)/2 = k(k+1)/2 So by the inductive hypothesis, we know that P(k+1) holds for some arbitrary k. Since k is arbitrary, P(n) holds for any positive integer.

Comment: You've made a mistake on P(1). You have E = 0 = 2. Your proof is otherwise sound, but you might want to explain why you are adding k to k(k-1)/2. This is a graph theory proof after all, not a number theory proof. I know and you know, but you shouldn't assume the reader will. :-)

Comment: Can you help me explain that? I don't really know what to use, I just know that I added k to the inductive hypothesis because k + the IH = the number of edges for k+1.....how would you explain it in the proof?

Comment: So when you add the $v_{k+1}$ vertex, for each vertex $v_{1}, ..., v_{k}$, we must add an edge $(v_{i}, v_{k+1})$ or $(v_{k+1}, v_{i})$ (but not both) for $i \in \{1, ..., k\}$. Thus, we have added $k$ edges to the tournament for the $k+1$ vertex. Now do your algebra.